# How to solve a hard annuity question, changing payments

Tags: finance

I am having a lot of confusion trying to work out this problem because it seems like a lot is going on all at once. I am looking for someone to please help.

A man would like to buy an annuity of $15$ years, that provides $30$ semi annual payments. The first payment $6$ months after the purchases the annuity. During a year, the payments are the same amount. After the first year however, at the beginning of each year the payments are decreased by $4$ percent.

if $i^{(2)}=0.10$, how much does this annuity cost?

My work:

Well I am quite confused on the wording, but I tried to make a time diagram. At the first 6 month mark, he makes a payment of P. 6 months later a payment of 0.96P, six months later 0.96P, six month later 0.92P, six month later 0.92P,..

6 months before the start of the fifteenth year a payment of 0.44P, six month later a final payment of 0.40P.

But now I don't know how I can use the semiannual rate and annuity formulas because I have different payments.

I tried to do it by discounting to bring everything in terms of value at time 0, but to sum all the inbetween without some sort of trick would be extremely difficult, I also am just overall confused on if that is even the correct method

Any help?

Comment: Several questions: Why would anybody buy an annuity that after you have purchased it, requires **you** to make payments for the next 15 years? Do you mean he receives semi-annual payments? Also, does your statement imply he gets one first payment, then the next (which is at the beginning of year two) declines by 4% already? And, does $i^{2)}=.1$ mean the interest rate is ten percent compounded semi-annually? Finally, I assume the annuity cost is the break-even cost at that interest rate; no profits for the annuity company. (ROTFL)

Comment: @MarkFischler Thanks for comment. I updated to more clearly state exactly what was asked. I do not know the reasoning of why such an annuity would be bought. His first payment is P, the next two are 0.96P, the next two are 0.92P, (that is how I interpret) and yes that is what the intrest stands for.

Comment: Do we assume the annual annuity payment is $1?

Comment: Well I think we just assume it is P

Comment: Because then it is called an m-thly paid annuity immediate

Comment: You cannot calculate the price (present value) of an annuity unless you know the payment. In this instance, I think it is expecting you to use annual payments of one

Comment: Do you know what the correct answer is? It would help because the question is ambiguous and could possibly have several solutions.

Comment: No I do not currently know the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53017/discussion-between-quantitative-and-personaa).

Comment: Are you sure that payments are decreased at the beginning of the year?

Comment: I wrote exactly how it was asked, so for now yes

Comment: The effective semiannual rate is 0.05

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=0.96, q=1.05$. and $a$ the initial annuity payment. Then the future value is

$\quad S_{30}=a\cdot \left[ q^{29}+q^{28}+dq^{27}+dq^{26}+\ldots+d^{14}q+d^{14} \right] \qquad (1)$

$ \frac{d}{q^2}S_{30} =a\cdot \left[\qquad \qquad \quad dq^{27}+dq^{26}+\ldots . +d^{14}q+d^{14}+\frac{d^{15}}{q}+\frac{d^{15}}{q^2} \right] \qquad (2)$

*Substracting (2) from (1)*

$S_{30}\cdot \left(1-\frac{d}{q^2}\right)=a\cdot \left(q^{29}+q^{28}-\frac{d^{15}}{q}-\frac{d^{15}}{q^2} \right)$

$S_{30}=a\cdot \frac{q^{29}+q^{28}-\frac{d^{15}}{q}-\frac{d^{15}}{q^2}}{1-\frac{d}{q^2}}$

Expanding the fraction by $q^2$

$S_{30}=a\cdot \frac{q^{31}+q^{30}-d^{15}q-d^{15}}{q^2-d}$

$S_{30}=a\cdot \frac{(1+q)\cdot (q^{30}-d^{15})}{q^2-d}$

And the present value is

$S_{0}=\frac{a}{q^{30}}\cdot \frac{(1+q)\cdot (q^{30}-d^{15})}{q^2-d}$

**Remark**

> After the first year however, at the beginning of each year the
>   payments are decreased by $4$ percent.

My interpetation is that  the payments at year $t$ is  $a\cdot 0.96^t$. The decrease of $4\%$ is referring to the level of payments of the previous year.

Comment: +1 for right answer assuming the first two payments are $a$. Your technique also works with the alternative interpretation, although the answer would be different.

Comment: What would It be under the other interpretation? could you explain that? Then I will be glad to accept this answer

Comment: @calculus  The first payment is a, the second is 0.96a

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

v+(1-.04)v^2+(1-.04)^2v^3+...+(1-.04)^14v^15

v[1+(.96/1.1025)^1+(.96/1.1025)^2+...+(.96/1.1025)^14]

Note: You have to use the effective annual rate of (1+.1/2)2=1.1025 in the v factor

=v[(1-(.96/1.1025)^15)/(1-(.96/1.1025))]=3.505

*This method uses the geometric series formula *

Comment: Concerning the second payment, it would still be 1 because the payments are decreased by 4% at the beginning of the year, and if the second PMT is in December, the 3rd june payment will have decreased by 4% since the start of the year

Comment: Yes, but the first payment does not happen when you buy the annuity, it happens six months later.

Answer (score 0):

Let the amount of the principle remaining in the annuity after $k$ payments have been made be $S_k$, and the initial payment be $P$.

Assume the semi-annual interest accrued is $q = 05$ (the semi-annual compounding of a ten percent annual rate) and the payments decrease at each payment $2i$ by a factor of $\delta = 0.96$.

Then we can see that payment $k$ is always $P\delta^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}$ where 
$\lfloor k/2 \rfloor$ means the greatest integer not exceeding $k/2$.  For example, payment $1$ is $P$, and payments $2$ and $3$ are both $P\delta^1$.

We cab cast the problem as follows:

For payments number $2i+1$,
$$
S_{2i+1} = (1+\alpha) S_{2i} - P \delta^i
$$
For payments number $2i$,
$$
S_{2i} = (1+\alpha) S_{2i-1}- P \delta^i
$$
And $S_{30}=$. Find $S_0$.

We solve this as follows:  First, to get rid of the ugly odd/even structure, we would like to know $S_{2i+2}$ in terms of $S_{2i}$:

$$S_{2i+2} = (1+\alpha) S_{2i+1}- P \delta^{i+1} = 
 (1+\alpha) \left( (1+\alpha) S_{2i} - P \delta^i\right) - P \delta^{i+1}\\
S_{2i+2} = (1+\alpha)^2  S_{2i} - (1+\alpha+\delta) P \delta^i
$$

This is a fairly easy series to sum in closed form, if you know a cute starting trick, and know how to sum a geometric series.  The cute trick is to let 
$ S_{2i} = (1+\alpha)^{2i}  a_{i}$; then $S_0 = a_0$ and the equation becomes
$$
(1+\alpha)^{2(i+1)} a_{i+1} = (1+\alpha)^{2(i+1)} a_i  - (1+\alpha+\delta) P \delta^i \mbox{ or}\\
a_{i+1} =  a_i  - \frac{(1+\alpha+\delta) P}{(1+\alpha)^{2(i+1)}}
$$
Since $a_i$ just decreases, each time, by $\frac{(1+\alpha+\delta) P}{(1+\alpha)^{2(i+1)}}$, clearly for all $i>0$
$$
a_i = a_0 - \sum_{k=0}^{i-1} \frac{(1+\alpha+\delta) P}{(1+\alpha)^{2k}}=
 a_0 - (1+\alpha+\delta) P\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}\frac{1}{(1+\alpha)^{2k}}
$$
and we know how to sum that geometric series, giving
$$
a_i = a_0 - \frac{1-(1+\alpha)^i}{1-(1+\alpha)} =  a_0 - (1+\alpha+\delta)\frac{(1+\alpha)^i-1}{\alpha} \\
S_{2i} = (1+\alpha)^{2i} \left( S_0 - (1+\alpha+\delta)\frac{(1+\alpha)^i-1}{\alpha} \right) 
$$
If we substitute $i=15, \alpha = 0.05, \delta = 0.95$ into $S_{30}=0$, we get
$$
S_{30} =0 = (1.05)^{30} \left( S_0 - 2.01P\frac{(1.05)^{15}-1}{0.5} \right) \\
S_0 = 2.01\frac{(1.05)^{15}-1}{0.5} \approx 21.579 P
$$

Comment: Can you explain why you get a diffirent answer then the one from calculus?

Comment: I have an error in my math. The answer by @callculus may also be wrong, but if so, it is in interpretation of the problem: That answer is right if you say that the first payment happens immediately upon purchase, so that the  first and second payments are both $a$.